# Testing spring security enabled api using postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, postman

I am working on a spring boot + spring security based application. I have used jdbcAuthentication to validate user. I have also configured custom login form.

After running the application I am able to successfully login and get the API response through browser but when I try to test the API using Postman I only get the HTML login page as response. How do I get the desired API json response?

My configuration file:

```
@Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                    throws Exception {
            System.out.println("auth manager called");
              auth. jdbcAuthentication() .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
              .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery) .dataSource(dataSource)
              .passwordEncoder(noop);

            }
         @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Http scurity called");
                http.httpBasic().
                and().
                        authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/db").hasAuthority("DBA")
                        .antMatchers("/user").hasAuthority("USER").anyRequest()
                        .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                        .successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
                        .usernameParameter("username")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                        .and().logout()
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
            }
```

My Controller file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView login() {
            System.out.println("/login called");
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.setViewName("login");
            return modelAndView;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
            public UserUniconnect home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

                Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                String currentUser = null;
                if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
                    currentUser = auth.getName();
                }

                User user1 = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                user1.getAuthorities();
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                System.out.println(request == null);
                Users u = (Users) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("user");
                Uniconnect uni = (Uniconnect) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("uniconnect");
                UserUniconnect uu = new UserUniconnect();
                uu.setUser(u);
                uu.setUniconnect(uni);

                return uu;
            }
```

I am returning java object as the response which spring boot is able to convert it into json format.

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRFXx.png)

Answer (score 3):

Setting up the Basic Auth parameters in Postman might help:
[image: Basic Auth settings in Postman]

It is most likely that you need to get your session id from a cookie after logging in manually with your browser and then provide this cookie to Postman just like this:

[image: JSESSIONID cookie]

Getting a cookie from browser differs depending on a browser itself, but Chrome and Firefox both have a Developer utils built in, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: Tried using cookies but my Post request somehow still gets me HTML login page.

Comment: Dunno, it should work if the cookie from browser is the right one, if it's named appropriately and if the contents of it is not messed up somehow.

Comment: Oh but of course you're using the httpBasic auth, my bad. There is a tab for it in Postman too! On the left side "Authorization", choose type: "Basic Auth" and try to type in your login and password. Maybe it will help.

Comment: please find the attached img.

Comment: You desire to test the json response from endpoint "/admin" but in your screenshot your target url is "/login". Of course Postman is sending the request there and you're getting the login page markup instead of json. Change the url. And the request type since you have "RequestMethod.GET" in code and POST in screenshot. It just won't map.

Comment: Judging by `.accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");` you have there, Postman got through the security layer with what it's got and the issue might be in your `public UserUniconnect home()` method (unlikely though, taking into account that it works with a browser). Drop a couple of breakpoints here and there and try to debug, maybe the state of security Context or type of Authentication will give you a hint.